# Parent div not expanding over child's padding

Tags: html, css

Consider :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div><a href="#" style="padding:5px 10px;text-decoration:none;color: black;border:1px solid black">CLICK</a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to wrap the div around the `a` click button. The div is only as tall as the text in the a block and doesn't consider the padding in its calculations.

How can I make the div wrap all of `a`? `overflow:hidden` and `overflow: auto` end up cutting out the top and bottom borders along with the part of the side borders above and below the text.

Comment: a {display: inline-block;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```css
a{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Test</h1>
    <div><a href="#" style="padding:5px 10px;text-decoration:none;color: black;border:1px solid black">CLICK</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/dywy6w8g/):

link css class :

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Note: avoid inline css for better readability and less errors